Common condition from two logic condition
I have two bit-level logic conditions which have some common inputs. I am looking for a way to identify a conditions which can make both logic condition as 1.
eg.
out1 = (a&b)|c;
out2 = (c|d)&b;
Expected Output : b&c (there can be multiple outputs).
Not able to target this problem, need a direction for this.
